# How to automatically filter each value using AttributeFilter or another transformer in FME?

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

FME 2016 Build 16494

I want to automatically filter each info field value and the workspace will run them one by one.

It's like:
[image]
and
[image]
and
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: The Workspace Runner is the transformer you will need, there is a little setup required, but will do what you are asking. Here is a good guide to setting that up https://community.safe.com/s/article/batch-processing-using-the-workspacerunner-1 Would upgrade to a newer FME (much faster for processing even between 2020 and 2021.)

Comment: i got it, thank you so much ! :)